# positioning div elements through position relative

Tags: html, css, css-position

I am playing around with webdesign, I always assumed that div's that are positioned relative, always are ordered in the way they are coded. But now I have a div that jumps above another although they are both relative.

A screenshot of the problem:

[image: Example of the problem]

Here is the code of my index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/layout.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/nav.css">
    <meta name="description" content="Website template 1">
    <meta name="keywords" content="template">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="MainContainer">
        <div id="HeaderContainer">
            <div id="NavigatieContainer">
                <ul id="nav">
                <!-- LVL 1 -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="Index.html">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="BodyContainer">
            <p>test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the code of my layout css:

```
/*Basic tags*/
body {
    background-color: #efebdf;
}

/*DIV ID's*/
div#MainContainer {
    width: 60%;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

div#HeaderContainer {
    position: relative;
}

div#NavigatieContainer {
    float: right;
}

div#BodyContainer {
    position: relative;
    background-color: brown;
}
```

and the code of my navigation css so far, although I don't think the problem is here:

```
a {
  color:#333333;
}
#nav {
  /*-webkit-box-shadow:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 0 1px 3px;*/
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
#nav li {
  margin-right: 10px; /*spacing tussen de list items*/
  float:left;/*zorgt voor naast elkaar te plaatsen*/
  list-style:none;/*Haalt list bolletjes weg*/
  position:relative;
  border-radius: 0.3em;
  background-color: #e2e0d3;
}
#nav a {
  color:black;
  display:block;
  font-weight:bold;
  margin:0;
  padding:8px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: It lowered it a wee bit, but only to the top of the header div, so it is still overlapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Adrift almost got it right, but he mentioned the wrong div. The overflow property should be on the HeaderContainer.

```
div#HeaderContainer {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

I've created a jsfiddle for you with the result. You might want to add it to any following questions as it allows us to easier detect the problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/7Kx9g/

A little more background informations; once an image floats it is no longer in the document and therefor does not reserve it's own height. A trick called [clearfix](http://www.webtoolkit.info/css-clearfix.html) can be used to prevent it, but it's an advanced way of using `overflow: auto;` or `overflow: hidden;`

Comment: Thank you, this fixed it entirely. And I will create an account and use it, this is the first time I have heard about jsfiddle but I'll use it in the future. I will rate you answer as soon as the timer expires.

Comment: There is still something I don't get about it though. Even if I made the navigation float, it is still in the header container, and I did not float that one?

Comment: That's correct. But you want to adapt the height of the header container to actually contain the navigation. Therefor we set this parameter on the header.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is caused by the float. Put `clear:both;` in the css for `div#BodyContainer`.

Look here. http://jsfiddle.net/aKy67/

Total agree @HC_

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how to use inline-block? IMO, it's much easier to organize things with `display:inline-block;` than to use `float`s, because `float` makes it ignore several CSS rules, and the larger your project becomes, the more troublesome this "rule-ignoring" has the POTENTIAL to become.